# startactivity creates two instances

Tags: java, android, start-activity

for my android app, I use a button to go to the next Activity.
the problem is when I touch the button on the screen one instance of the activity is created but when
I use performClick() method to click the button programmatically, it creates two instances of the activity. ( performClick() is called from a callback method).
I used the CLEAR_TOP FLAG but it seems to break the back button. 
Any idea how to solve this problem ?

this is what my code looks like:

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(final View v) {
               startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
         }
       });
}
private void A_callback_method(){
      if (some_condition_to_launch_activity){
         btn.performClick();
       } 
}
```

Comment: Could `A_callback_method` be called twice? What calls it?

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple trick. create function

```
private void function_name(){
    startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class));
}
```

Then on the button onClickListener

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(final View v) {
               function_name();
         }
       });
```

and also inside A_callback_method

```
private void A_callback_method(){
      if (some_condition_to_launch_activity){
         function_name();
       } 
}
```

hope this will solve your problems.

Answer (score -1):

I succesfully did a work around to solve this problem by adding a boolean variable intialise it to false in the onResume() method  and then did the following:

```
private boolean clicked_btn;
private void A_callback_method(){
      if ((some_condition_to_launch_activity)&&!clicked_btn){
          clicked_btn=true;
          btn.performClick();
       } 
}
```